# How to write calculated fields to evaluate variable row sums in Tableau?

Tags: excel, tableau-api, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I had posted the question in Tableau community, but did not get a solution there for 20 days now. Hence posting it here (the Excel sheet containing the data as well as the desired output, and the Tableau workbook are attached in the post in the link):

https://community.tableau.com/thread/317048

Basically, how do I replicate Excel formulae like these in Tableau:

```
Output value in cell [i] = (Sum of some row(s) in all columns except in column[i] +/- Sum of some other row(s) in all columns except in column[i])/(Sum of some yet other row(s) in all columns except in column[i])
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am absolutely at the end of my wits, as I've never worked with Tableau before, but can't escape this task that has been dumped on me. So, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Step one is to put a value in cell A1

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Ok, let's say I put 0 in there. What to do next?

Comment: Your data should have one header row listing field names, followed by a series of data rows, and no total row. So A1 should be the name of the field that has values A,B,C etc, let’s assume you call it Project. You’ll probably want to use Tableau’s pivot feature next to simplify your analysis, by making the data appear to have simply 3 fields: Project Level and Say Value.

Comment: couldn't understand calculation you need? what should be the output of rows and columns in excel? in simple words?

Comment: @Siva `Output value in cell [i] = (Sum of some row(s) in all columns except in column[i] +/- Sum of some other row(s) in all columns except in column[i])/(Sum of some yet other row(s) in all columns except in column[i])`
Its actually better understood when you look at the attached excel sheet in the link.

Comment: @Kristada673 If you are using a background tool like python or MySQL to feed data in Tableau, it would be much easier to perform these calculations there. If its to be done in Tableau, you can first pivot your data set and then use the combination of Window_sum and Lookup functions in Tableau for your purpose. To know more about these functions, see Tableau help page: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm.

Comment: why did you delete your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533202/how-to-extract-text-from-website-when-clicking-on-something-does-not-affect-the  It was a good one IMO and I had written an answer for you.

Comment: @QHarr Oh! The question was voted to close by 2 people already, and was also marked as duplicate. That's why I deleted it.

Comment: you don't need selenium to answer that question you posed. It was actually an interesting problem to solve. Personally, I don't think that indicated dupe was a suitable target in that nothing in that answer would have helped you answer your problem other than how to launch selenium (which, as I said, isn't needed). In case you are interested please see: https://pastebin.com/5tJBKk1B

Answer (score 1):

I posted a solution for X in your thread on Tableau's [forums](https://community.tableau.com/message/990840#990840)

You'll need to learn Tableau table calc well to build on this approach - unfortunately nested table calcs are one of the more complicated topics to learn in Tableau (but also very useful). So expect it take a little time to learn that topic well.

Comment: Thanks for that Alex. It would be really helpful if you could also list out the exact steps you took, as I have never used Tableau before, like I mentioned in the question. For example, when you say, "Using the pivot feature on the data source page...", how exactly to do that in Tableau? And how to construct the nested table step by step? Things like that. Thanks again.

Comment: Im pressed for time now, so have to refer you to the online help. Pivoting data is described there well. Table calcs have a good intro section in the help as well, but you’ll have to read and play a bit to get them. I’d start with books by Joshua Milligan. Good luck. Sorry that your first problem set required one of the trickier features. Most people can easily get through many projects before needing to learn about nested table calcs.